# How to get value from XML using C# or VB?

Tags: c#, saml-2.0

The Below xml format data is part of the SAML response of assertion XML, i dont konw how to pick the NorBefore and NotOnOrAfter from condtions node and AttributeValue from AttributeStatement node, so please help me to get these values from these xml. I am using visual studio 2005 and i need a code in C# or vb.

```
<ns2:Conditions NotBefore="2014-01-16T22:10:09Z" NotOnOrAfter="2014-01-16T22:12:09Z">
<ns2:AudienceRestriction>
<ns2:Audience>namecomponent:test.comp.com</ns2:Audience>
</ns2:AudienceRestriction>
</ns2:Conditions>
<ns2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2014-01-16T22:10:39Z" SessionIndex="8cILoZqzVAFS2t8zF65fmT2rIFE=F5zAiA==" SessionNotOnOrAfter="2014-01-16T22:12:09Z">
<ns2:AuthnContext>
<ns2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</ns2:AuthnContextClassRef>
</ns2:AuthnContext>
</ns2:AuthnStatement>
<ns2:AttributeStatement>
<ns2:Attribute Name="NameID" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
<ns2:AttributeValue>EMP10344</ns2:AttributeValue>
</ns2:Attribute>
</ns2:AttributeStatement>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In VB.NET, it's quite simple. First, you'll have to define the namespace in the declaration section of your module:

```
Imports <xmlns:ns2="http://SomeNamespace">
```

Replace SomeNamespace with the namespace declared as `ns2` in the header of your XML file.

Then load the XML into an [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and read the value using VB's LINQ-to-XML syntax:

```
Dim notBefore = xdoc.Root.<ns2:Conditions>.@NotBefore
```